# How to fix:android.app.RemoteServiceException: Bad notification posted from package XXX: Couldn't inflate contentViewsandroid.view.InflateException

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-resources

I'm seeing the following exception in crash logs:

```
android.app.RemoteServiceException: Bad notification posted from package XXX: Couldn't inflate contentViewsandroid.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1797)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6651)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:824)
```

But, my custom notification layout has never defined this class label：`com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout`

Moreover, my custom layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/root"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/local_push_bg_color"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="@dimen/dp_6">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/dp_26">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_local_push_logo"
            android:drawablePadding="@dimen/dp_6"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="@color/local_push_title_text_color"
            android:text="@string/local_push_title"
            android:textSize="@dimen/sp_14"
            tools:ignore="RelativeOverlap" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_next"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/dp_26"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_local_push_next"
            tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/v_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dp_10"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_push_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/shape_bg_local_push_content" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_local_push_play" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_push_content_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/dp_10"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:maxLines="2"
            tools:text="asdaksjdllasfjasldjkasfljkaslkfjlsjafsafjk"
            android:textColor="@color/c_white"
            android:textSize="@dimen/sp_14" />

    </RelativeLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/v_search_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dp_10"
        android:background="@drawable/shape_bg_local_push_search"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="@dimen/dp_8">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_push_search_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_local_push_search"
            android:drawablePadding="@dimen/dp_6"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:maxLines="1"
            tools:text="what the fk"
            android:textColor="@color/local_push_search_text_color"
            android:textSize="@dimen/sp_12" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

as you see, There is no class label reported above.

So far, we have found three different error messages for the same 
custom notification layout:

1. Error inflating class com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
2. Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
3. Error inflating class android.widget.TextView

Comment: The error doesn't reference "support".  MDC is not mutually exclusive with androidx. What _is_ your custom notification layout?